# Laravel scope custom field value for model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model as follows

```
class WorkingTime extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'working_times';
    protected $fillable = ['day', 'start_time', 'finish_time', 'user_id'];
    public function scopeAfterStart($query, $start)
    {
        return $query->where('start_time', '<=', $start);
    }

    public function scopeBeforeFinish($query, $finish)
    {
        return $query->where('finish_time', '>=', $finish);
    }
}
```

and I can use the following query

```
WorkingTime::afterStart(1200)->beforeFinish(1800)->get();
```

what I need to do is, in `working_times` table when the `start_time` > `finish_time` value, I have to check if `finish_time + 2400 >= $finish`. To be more specific, something like the following query has to be happened

```
with new_working_times as (
    select       
        start_time,
        case when start_time > finish_time then
            finish_time + 2400 
        else
            finish_time
        end as finish_time   
)
select * from new_working_times
where finish_time > {finishTime} and start_time < {start_time}
```

How can I do this via eloquent and scope?

Comment: I think you should look into accessor. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Why not just pass the two values to the scope? `public function scopeBeforeFinish($query, $start, $finish) { if($start > $finish) $finish = $finish+ 2400; return $query->where('finish_time', '>=', $finish); }`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ the `$finish` is ok, I need some thing like `$query->where('finish_time' + 2400, '>=', $finish); `

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko that is a solution came to my mind too, but what about the rest of the project? I need to add `2400` just in this query not all the project